# Integration using mixed variables

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

determine the integral:

I=  $\int_A^B${[$12x^2y+(\frac{y}{x})+4x]$dx + ($2y+4x^3+log_ex$) dy}

where the (x,y) coordinates of A & B are (1,1) and (2,2), respectively.

---

I tried seperating the integral into two part and then integrated each part with respect to its variable but ended up with a function and not a value , so how can  i fully integrate it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you integrate over the straight line between $A$ and $B$:

First, find a parametrization of the curve. Here, $(x,y)=(t,t)$, $1\leq t\leq 2$ will do. Then $dx=dt$ and $dy=dt$, so your integral, according to the definition of curve integral, transforms into
$$
\int_1^2 12t^2t+\frac{t}{t}+4t+2t+4t^3+\log_{e} t\,dt.
$$
Can you take it from here?

**Edit**

Since you noted that there exists a potential, and actually had calculated it, here comes a way using it: Let
$$
u(x,y)=2x^2+4x^3y+y^2+y\log_e x
$$
be the potential. Then, the integral you want to calculate is just $u(2,2)-u(1,1)$, i.e. the value of the potential at the end-point minus the potential at the start-point.

Comment: i have also found that this is an exact differential and found the parent function, does this help in any way?